# Loading pokemon from xml file based on name

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML file with 600+ pokemon in, each pokemon has base stats, when a pokemon is selected from a dropdown list I want to load in the pokemons base stats.

XML file is as follows:

```xml
<Pokemon>
   <Name>Bulbasaur</Name>

   <BaseStats>
     <Health>5</Health>
     <Attack>5</Attack>
     <Defense>5</Defense>
     <SpecialAttack>7</SpecialAttack>
     <SpecialDefense>7</SpecialDefense>
     <Speed>5</Speed>
   </BaseStats>
</Pokemon>
<Pokemon>
   <Name>Ivysaur</Name>

   <BaseStats>
     <Health>7</Health>
     <Attack>7</Attack>
     <Defense>6</Defense>
     <SpecialAttack>9</SpecialAttack>
     <SpecialDefense>8</SpecialDefense>
     <Speed>5</Speed>
   </BaseStats>
</Pokemon>
```

My code is:

```cs
XDocument pokemonDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\users\reece\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Pokesheet\Pokesheet\Files\pokemon.xml");

var pokemon = pokemonDoc.Descendants("Pokemon").Select(x => new
{
    name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
    health = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Health"),
    attack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Attack"),
    defense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Defense"),
    specialAttack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialAttack"),
    specialDefense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialDefense"),
    speed = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Speed"),
});

baseHp.Value = pokemon.health;
baseAttack.Value = pokemon.attack;
baseDefense.Value = pokemon.defense;
baseSpAttack.Value = pokemon.specialAttack;
baseSpDefense.Value = pokemon.specialDefense;
baseSpeed.Value = pokemon.speed;
```

I want it to only create a pokemon when the name in the xml file matches the name the user selects, how do I do this?

Comment: "can someone please help me on this" -- Help you do what? What is your question? Are you getting an exception somewhere?

Comment: Don't have the time right now, but you are missing a `Where` to select the Pokemon you are looking for and a `Single` to have the correct data type...

Comment: "i want it to only create a pokemon when the name in the xml file matches the name the user selects" currently it creates every single pokemon in the xml file (which i dont want) is there a way to restrict it so that it will only create a "pokemon" when the pokemon element name equals what the user has selected

Comment: Ok someone gave answer already to use LINQ's `Where` method. As an aside from your question, note that the xml file you pasted is invalid as it has multiple root elements so your code gives me an exception when trying to load or parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, i used your answers, but we were comparing them wrong in the where statement, the finished answer is this:

```
var pokemon = pokemonDoc.Descendants("Pokemon").Select(x => new
        {

            name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
            health = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Health"),
            attack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Attack"),
            defense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Defense"),
            specialAttack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialAttack"),
            specialDefense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialDefense"),
            speed = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Speed"),

        }).Where(x => x.name.ToString() == cbSpecies.SelectedItem.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

        baseHp.Value = pokemon.health;
        baseAttack.Value = pokemon.attack;
        baseDefense.Value = pokemon.defense;
        baseSpAttack.Value = pokemon.specialAttack;
        baseSpDefense.Value = pokemon.specialDefense;
        baseSpeed.Value = pokemon.speed;
```

Comment: Please provide a full sample of your code next time

Answer (score 2):

```
 var pokemon = pokemonDoc.Descendants("Pokemon").Select(x => new
    {

        name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
        health = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Health"),
        attack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Attack"),
        defense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Defense"),
        specialAttack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialAttack"),
        specialDefense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialDefense"),
        speed = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Speed"),

    }).Where(x => x.name == "yourName").FirstOrDefault();
```

This should bring you the pokemon for the selected name or null if it doesn't find any

Comment: You have to call `Where` first, and `Select` at the end of your lambda expression

Comment: You should call where first so you do not create the classes for those you don't want. You can also use FirstOrDefaul(x => x.name == "yourName")

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
// Your user selected pokemon
string selectedPokemon = pokemonFromDropDownList.name; 

var pokemon = pokemonDoc.Descendants("Pokemon").Where(p => p.name == selectedPokemon).Select(x => new
{

    name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
    health = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Health"),
    attack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Attack"),
    defense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Defense"),
    specialAttack = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialAttack"),
    specialDefense = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("SpecialDefense"),
    speed = (int)x.Element("BaseStats").Element("Speed"),

});

    // Then do what ever you want with it
    if(pokemon != null) 
    {
        baseHp.Value = pokemon.health;
        baseAttack.Value = pokemon.attack;
        baseDefense.Value = pokemon.defense;
        baseSpAttack.Value = pokemon.specialAttack;
        baseSpDefense.Value = pokemon.specialDefense;
        baseSpeed.Value = pokemon.speed;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do stuff if it not exist...
    }
```

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat.  Thomas is filtering the xml file.  The following code is filtering the results or original code :  var abcPokemon = pokemon.Where(x => x.name == "abc").First();