# Which is better for performance: referencing external documents or internal collections?

Tags: c#, xml, performance, collections

I recently came upon this post ([Loading pokemon from xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168239/loading-pokemon-from-xml-file-based-on-name)) which got me thinking, is it better to reference a large amount of objects in an external document (such as an xml file) or would using a collection (such as a list or dictionary) be better performance wise?

I haven't been programming for very long so I appologize if this is a "common-knowledge" type of question, but I am mainly focused on the performance aspects in terms of

1. How is the memory accessed? For example, would the collections require more use of RAM as opposed to the xml file using more memory on a hard drive?
2. Which would be the faster process when accessing a random object? I.E. a list of 100, 1000, or even 10,000 objects? My guess is that it would be quicker to access an internal list or dictionary than it would be to read an external xml file and try to pull in the object info.
3. Is one of the options considered better programming practice than the other? Is it just preference? ( I realize this isn't necessarily a performance question but I believe it is still worth knowing).

Using the example I found in the post (pokemon), my first thought would be 1 of 2 things for making the collection internal.

1. I would create a base class that all pokemon derived from, then child classes that had the specific species of pokemon for the individual info (though I believe there are several hundred pokemon so this may not be practical).
2. I would create a class called pokemon with several properties that each pokemon would have (such as a name, species, etc...)

From here I would likely make a list or dictionary that I would use to reference each pokemon when needed.

As an alternative, I would likely do as the poster of the question did, which would be to create an xml file with the list of pokemon, and then call upon the file whenever it was needed.

I included this info so that the 3 questions above could have have some sort of context, but again, I am mainly concerned with the performance of internal collections vs external documents when there is a large number of objects.

Note: the external documents don't necessarily have to be xml but that is what is used in the post that I found.

Comment: If you want to know which is faster, try both, and *find out for yourself*.

Comment: I'm not working on a particular project that would use this but I was more just looking to see if anyone who had done a project using a large list of objects had already gone through the thought process and what they came up with. I'd prefer to not reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Comment: So you don't actually need to know at all?  If so, why ask the question?  If you need to know, write a simple test and find out.

Comment: This again depends on your envireonment and your buisness-case. Do all objects even *fit* into your memory? The question on performance is irrelevant if you don´t have enough RAM.

Comment: The question was asked more out of curiosity than a "need". Though I haven't been part of SO for very long so if this would be better asked (or not asked) somewhere else then I would be more than happy to remove it. Certainly there are some aspects of the question that I will be working on myself (seeing how quickly the list can be accessed) but in terms of how the memory is stored or what is considered good programming practice (if there is a preference at all) I am lacking in that knowledge.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Such questions are indeed not appropriate on the site.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Do both cases (collections and external docs) require a lot of RAM usage? My initial thought would be that the xml file wouldn't require very much RAM at all, but would rather use mostly memory on a hard drive to hold the file. Is this an incorrect assumption?

Comment: @Servy, how do I go about removing this question? I am unable to find a button that would allow me to do this.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 You no longer can, because people have since posted answers that don't' actually answer your question.  There will have been a "delete" button allowing you to delete it until just a minute ago.

Comment: @Servy is there a way I can refer this to a moderator to have it removed then?

Comment: @Sudsy1002 You can flag the post by clicking the "flag" link and ask a moderator to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Internal Collections offers way better performance to Serialized/ Deserialized Content.

It really boils down to what your requirements are, rather deciding things in a more generic way. When your data is seldom accessed by the application and your application is a long running application you can keep to serialize the data in a file and deserialize them as and when required to save memory.  But in more cases it's not a great deal, especially with work stations having big chunks of memory.  I would rather stay away from this approach.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer:

> How is the memory accessed? For example, would the collections require
>   more use of RAM as opposed to the xml file using more memory on a hard
>   drive?

RAM use would depend on whether you load the whole xml file in at once or not.

> Is one of the options considered better programming practice than the
>   other? Is it just preference? ( I realize this isn't necessarily a
>   performance question but I believe it is still worth knowing).

The most obvious advantage for an external resource is that you don't need to recompile the whole program every time you change data. There are other advantages/disadvantages which depend on the size of the program, but generally, any data that you may want to change should not need recompiling to update.